# Loop through associative array and assign values

Tags: php, arrays, loops, multidimensional-array, foreach

I have an array:

```
$instructions = array (
array("step_no"=>"1","description"=>"Ensure that you have sufficient balance"),
array("step_no"=>"2","description"=>"Approve the request sent to your phone")
);
```

What I want is to loop through this array, which I have done, but I am now confused because I don't know how to get the output I desire.

```
foreach ($array as $key => $value) { 
//echo $key . "\n"; 
foreach ($value as $sub_key => $sub_val) {      
    if (is_array($sub_val)) { 
        //echo $sub_key . " : \n"; 
        foreach ($sub_val as $k => $v) { 
            echo "\t" .$k . " = " . $v . "\n"; 
        } 
    } else { 
        echo $sub_key . " = " . $sub_val . "\n"; 
    } 
  } 
}
```

The above code loops through the array, but this line of code:

```
echo $sub_key . " = " . $sub_val . "\n";
```

gives me:

```
step_no = 1 description = Ensure that you have sufficient balance step_no = 2 description = Approve the request sent to your phone
```

when I change it to:

```
echo $sub_val . "\n";
```

it gives me:

```
1 Ensure that you have sufficient balance 2 Approve the request sent to your phone
```

But I what I truly want is:

```
1. Ensure that you have sufficient balance 
2. Approve the request sent to your phone
```

Is this possible at all? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$instructions = array (
    array("step_no"=>"1","description"=>"Ensure that you have sufficient balance"),
    array("step_no"=>"2","description"=>"Approve the request sent to your phone")
);

foreach($instructions as $instruction) {
    echo $instruction['step_no'] . '. ' . $instruction['description'] . "\n";
}
```

If it's HTML you may want to use `<ol>` and `<li>`.

Comment: this was fast, woow, very fewer lines too. Suited my needs perfectly. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

It smells like you are not running this script in command line but in browser. If so, then `\n` makes no visual effect (unless within `<pre>` block) and you u must use HTML tag `<br />` instead. Also, drop concatenation madness and use variable substitution:

```
echo "{$sub_key}. = {$sub_val}<br/>";
```

Comment: Ok. Thanks for the advice.

Answer (score 1):

You can simple achieve this way

```
<?php
    $instructions = array (
                           array("step_no"=>"1","description"=>"Ensure that you have sufficient balance"),
                           array("step_no"=>"2","description"=>"Approve the request sent to your phone")
);

   foreach($instructions as $instruction){

       echo $instruction['step_no'].'. '.$instruction['description'].PHP_EOL;
   }
?>
```

Alway keep it simple.

Comment: I'm a huge fan of keeping codes simple, I'm not very good at all with loops and arrays, that's why I browsed a lot of sites just to come up with that code, it seemed to work, that's why I decided to use it with trying to make further adjustments to it to avoid spoiling it.